# Pass part of model to View problem in Asp.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net, jquery, asp.net-mvc-2

I really didn't know what title to give this question, but I'll explain here:

I have a View with a bunch of input fields in a table. Each row in the table represents a task, and each column a weekday, and the input fields in each cell are there to let the user input hours worked for that task and day.

I then have a submit button to post the hours when the user wants to save. But here's the problem: Each timesegment (as the object that holds hours is called) also has the property Description, to let the user write a description of what has been done for a particular time segment reported.

So how could I get the description property for the selected timesegment input field and show it in another "description" input field, and then let the user modify the description and save it with the timesegment?

Here's what I've done so far:

Action method to get the description:

```
    public ActionResult GetDescription(string name, int number, int year)
    {
        try
        {
            int taskId = Int32.Parse(name.SubstringAfter("Tasks[").Substring(0, 1));
            int timeSegmentId = Int32.Parse(name.SubstringAfter("CurrentTimeSegments[").Substring(0, 1));
            List<Task> tasks = _repository.GetCurrentTasks(number, year);
            var description = tasks[taskId].CurrentTimeSegments[timeSegmentId].Description;

            return Content(description);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            return Content("");
        }
    }
```

jQuery:

```
    function getDescription() {
        $('.hourInput').focus(function () {
            var name = $(this).attr('name');
            var number = '<%: Model.WeekNumber %>';
            var year = '<%: Model.Year %>';
            var url = '<%=Url.Action("GetDescription", "Timesheet") %>';
            $.get(url, { name: name, number: number, year: year }, function (data) {
                $('#description').val(data);
            });
        });
    }
```

Now, as you can see, I have to parse the name attribute of the input field to get the object I'm after, and this seems like a bit of a hack... But it's the only way I can see to get this information. So my question is, is there another cleaner way to do this?

UPDATE:

Here's the part that creates the input fields in a nested for loop (looping through each task, and then for each task all its timesegments):

```
<% for (int i = 0; i < Model.Tasks.Count; i++)
           {
               var task = Model.Tasks[i];
        %>
        <tr class="taskrow">
            <td>
                <input type="button" value="Delete" id="<%:i %>" class="deletebutton" />
            </td>
            <td class="customer">
                <%: task.Project.Customer.Name %>
            </td>
            <td class="project">
                <%: task.Project.Name %>
            </td>
            <td class="task">
                <%: task.Name %>
            </td>
            <% for (int j = 0; j < task.CurrentTimeSegments.Count; j++)
               { %>
            <td>
                <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Tasks[i].CurrentTimeSegments[j].TimeSpanHours, new { @class = "hourInput" })%>
                <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Tasks[i].CurrentTimeSegments[j].TimeSpanHours)%>
            </td>
            <% } %>
            <td class="hourSum"><%:task.WeekTaskHours %></td>
        </tr>
        <% } %>
```

Note that this code is in a partialview if it matters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use the `$.data` jQuery function to save extra information in your `this` element of the `getDescription` method. You need to do that when you create this element. I don't know how you do that and if it is possible for you in your current design.

to save the information it would be:

```
$(element).data('taskId', taskId);
$(element).data('timeSegmentId', timeSegmentId);
```

If you give the code where you create this element, I could help you.

Then the `getDescription` method would be

```
$('.hourInput').focus(function () {
   var taskId = $(this).data('taskId');
   vat timeSegmentId = $(this).data('timeSegmentId');
   var number = '<%: Model.WeekNumber %>';
   var year = '<%: Model.Year %>';
   var url = '<%=Url.Action("GetDescription", "Timesheet") %>';
   $.get(url, { taskId : taskId, timeSegmentId: timeSegmentId, number: number, year: year }, function (data) {
      $('#description').val(data);
   });
});
```

and so in your controller

```
public ActionResult GetDescription(string taskId, string timeSegmentId, int number, int year)
{
   try
   {
      List<Task> tasks = _repository.GetCurrentTasks(number, year);
      var description = tasks[taskId].CurrentTimeSegments[timeSegmentId].Description;

      return Content(description);
   }
   catch (Exception)
   {
      return Content("");
   }
}
```

EDIT:

According to how you create the input text boxes, I think you can do:

```
<td>
   <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Tasks[i].CurrentTimeSegments[j].TimeSpanHours, new { @class = "hourInput", id = "uniqueId_" + i + j })%>
   <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Tasks[i].CurrentTimeSegments[j].TimeSpanHours)%>
   <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {
         var selector = '#uniqueId_<%=i %><%=j %>';
         $(selector).data('taskId', <%=i %>);
         $(selector).data('timeSegmentId', <%=j %>);
      });
   </script>
</td>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It sounds interesting, I'm just not sure I can do this with my code... As you can see from my update the input fields are created in a loop in a partial view. So I have no idea how I would add data through jQuery to each field as it is being created within this loop?

Comment: I edited my answer to provide you how you could initialise the data in your input boxes. However I don't really like it, because you put script inside the HTML...

Comment: Well, no, that doesn't feel any better than what I already had, and I'm no expert at jQuery, but I don't see how it could work - the (document).ready function only runs when the document is first loaded as far as I know?

Comment: of course it works. The document.ready is loaded on your browser and set all the .data in the text input. I change a bit the code in order to set a unique id to the text input, so it looks a little nicer.

Comment: Ok. I ended up doing it slightly differently, using the new custom attributes in HTML5, but I'll credit you with the answer since you got me on the track toward this solution! Thanks